# How can I use python to input multiple text in excel and split them by multiple delimiter

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using python to deal with multiple text in excel, and I need to input the text at sheet1 and
split the data in sheet2.

The text is something like.
[text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3kBj.png)
The text is including a lot of delimiter e.g.#,~ and two space, one space.
so I tried to input them first

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
    path = os.getcwd()
    csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))
    
    
    for a in csv_files:
        print(a)
    data_list = []
    
    for file in csv_files:
        data_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))
        print(data_list)
    
    sheet1 = pd.concat(data_list, axis=0, sort=True)
    sheet1.to_excel('test1.xlsx', encoding='utf-8',index=True,header=True)
```

I don't know how the split them first so I tried to put them in one sheet, and create the dataframe and split them.

```
    df2=pd.DataFrame()
    df2=sheet1["#xpost 2"].str.replace('#',' ').str.replace(' +',' ').str.lstrip().str.split(' ', expand=True)
    
    with pd.ExcelWriter("test1.xlsx", mode="a", engine="openpyxl",if_sheet_exits="new") as writer:
        df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='sheet1',index=True,header=True,)
```

finally I got the results as image, have same index for each text result, but that is not I want.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3kBj.png)

I'd like my output to look like this, split them by multiple delimiter and arrange them by columns automatically.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kgh9.png)

Is there have more elegant way of doing this?
Thanks a lot.